# MySQL: Querying a table and possibly replacing some fields with values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Table1 is our main table of data and Table2 has a subset of the Table1 columns and a subset of the records contained in Table1. You can see Table2 as a table holding corrected values for some of Table1's records.

I want to query one or more records from these tables using the following rules:

(1) If the record's id exists only in Table1, I want to get all the columns back for that record (equivalent to `select * from Table1 where Table1.id in (1, 2, 3)`)

(2) If the record's id exists in both Table1 and Table2, then for each column in Table2, the Table2 value should get precedence over the corresponding value of Table1. For all columns in Table1 but not in Table2, we return the Table1 values.

For example:

Table1

```
| id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | AA-1-1  | AA-1-2  | AA-1-3  | AA-1-4  |
| 2  | AA-2-1  | AA-2-2  | AA-2-3  | AA-2-4  |
| 3  | AA-3-1  | AA-3-2  | AA-3-3  | AA-3-4  |
```

Table2

```
| id | Column2 | Column4 |
--------------------------
| 1  | ZZ-1-2  | ZZ-1-4  |
| 3  | ZZ-3-2  | ZZ-3-4  |
```

Querying for records with id in (1, 2, 3) should return:

```
| id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | AA-1-1  | ZZ-1-2  | AA-1-3  | ZZ-1-4  |
| 2  | AA-2-1  | AA-2-2  | AA-2-3  | AA-2-4  |
| 3  | AA-3-1  | ZZ-3-2  | AA-3-3  | ZZ-3-4  |
```

Is it possible to come up with such a query? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id, Column1, IFNULL(table2.Column2, table1.Column2),
    column3, IFNULL(table2.Column4, table1.Column4)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE (table1.id IN (1,2,3))
```

`IFNULL(a,b)` translates to `IF (a IS NULL) then b else a` - it'll return the second argument if the first argument is null, otherwise it returns the first argument.

Comment: could add as Column2, Column4